# Selection of pixels in a specific area on image in R

Tags: r, image-processing, pixel, raster

I have an image with a black background and with many white spots everywhere. I just need to study the white pixel in the center area. This studied area is a rectangular where each edge is at a distance of 50 pixels from the edges of the image.

So I would like to select the white pixels inside this area. I defined the 4 corners (xi, xf, yi and yf) but how to select the white pixel in the studied area?

```
library(EBImage)
library(ggplot2)
image <- readImage('C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Cluster/Test.png')
display(image , method = "raster")

# definition of the 4 corner of the selection box
tolerance <- 50
xi <- 0 + tolerance
xf <- dim(image )[1] - tolerance
yi <- 0 + tolerance
yf <- dim(image )[2] - tolerance
```

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question ? For instance what do you mean by selecting ? What do you want to do with this selection ? Do you want to process those white pixels as a whole or as separate patches ?

Comment: Laurent, your question is still not clear. The description you give suggests you want to crop the image by 50 pixels on each side. Is this correct?

Comment: I would guess that "study the white pixels" could either be to study the objects defined by white pixels as an aggregate or individually. If it is individually, the function `bwlabel` in EBImage performs the binary segmentation to extract the connected groups of pixels. The function `computeFeatures` gives access to many properties about those segmented objects.